# Expected number of cards fixed in a deck after a certain operation

Tags: probability, problem-solving

**Problem:** Given a standard deck of $52$ cards, extract 26 of the cards at random in one of the $52 \choose{26}$ possible ways and place them on the top of the deck is the same relative order as they were before being selected. What is the expected number of cards that now occupy the same position in the deck as before?

This nice problem is due to Jim Propp.

Answer (score 4):

In a similar vein as Ross's answer, but with less calculation required: A card remains fixed at the bottom if it lies below all selected cards. Perform the selection by shuffling $26$ selected and $26$ unselected cards. By symmetry, the probability for $1$ unselected card to lie below all $26$ selected cards is $\frac1{27}$. There are $26$ unselected cards, so by linearity of expectation $\frac{26}{27}$ of them are expected to lie below all selected cards. The situation at the top is analogous, so the overall expectation is $\frac{52}{27}$.

Answer (score 2):

The top card remains if it is selected, probability $\frac {26}{52}$.  The second remains if both the top two are selected, probability $\frac {26 \cdot 25}{52 \cdot 51}=\frac {(52-2)!26!}{52!(26-2)!}$ and so on through the first $26$ cards-we have the top $n$ in place with probability $\frac {(52-n)!26!}{52!(26-n)!}$.  Counting up from the bottom is the same-card $52-m$ is in place if all the cards from $52-m$ through $52$ were not selected, with probabilty $\frac {(52-m)!26!}{52!(26-m)!}$.  So the expected number is $2\sum_{n=1}^{26}\frac {(52-n)!26!}{52!(26-n)!}=\frac {52}{27}\approx 1.926$

Comment: I'm not sure this is exact, as there is correlation between the cards selected and the cards not selected.

Comment: Yes, it's exact; the correlations don't matter because of the linearity of expectation. But you've got an extra factor of $n$; you should just be adding up the indicator variables themselves. The result is

$$
2\sum_{n=1}^{26}\frac{\binom{26}n}{\binom{52}n}= \frac{2\cdot26}{26+1}=\frac{52}{27}\approx1.926\;.
$$

Comment: @joriki:  thanks.  fixed.

Comment: How is the probability being calculated? How is it 26/52? Also, why have you not multiplied the probability by an "x" since expected is Sum of xP(X=x)?

Please explain. Thanks

Comment: @S_M Do you see why the chance the top card is in place is $26/52$.  joriki and I both explain it.

Comment: No, sorry I don't. The probability that the Exactly 1 card is in its position, which can either be the top card or the last card = 50C25/50C26. Because, we fix the top card A_1, and then count the number of other collections with A_1. Furthermore, we must also simultaneously ensure that we are not EVER including the A_2, and always including A_52, in these collections, because if we include A_2 then the number cards that would end up in the same position will be 2, and not 1.

IMHO. Where am I going wrong? Please help.

Comment: You chose $26$ cards out of the $52$.  If they include the original top card, it stays in place.  If not, there is a new top card.  That gives the $26/52$ without thinking about the other cards at all.